# Netbeans linker problems. openGL/GLFW

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to set up openGL in netbeans using GLFW, and I just can't get the libraries to link properly. I have all the libraries where they are supposed to be, I've tried changing the order of the links all around, and I just don't know what to do.

**Here is the code:**

```
// This is a small test application for GLFW.
// The program opens a window (640x480), and renders a spinning colored
// triangle (it is controlled with both the GLFW timer and the mouse).

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#define GLFW_DLL
#include <GL/glfw.h>

int main(void) {
    int width, height, x;
    double t;

    // Initialise GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    if (!glfwOpenWindow(640, 480, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window\n");

        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwSetWindowTitle("Spinning Triangle");

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwEnable(GLFW_STICKY_KEYS);

    // Enable vertical sync (on cards that support it)
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    do {
        t = glfwGetTime();
        glfwGetMousePos(&x, NULL);

        // Get window size (may be different than the requested size)
        glfwGetWindowSize(&width, &height);

        // Special case: avoid division by zero below
        height = height > 0 ? height : 1;

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        // Clear color buffer to black
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Select and setup the projection matrix
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(65.0f, (GLfloat) width / (GLfloat) height, 1.0f, 100.0f);

        // Select and setup the modelview matrix
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluLookAt(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Eye-position
                0.0f, 20.0f, 0.0f, // View-point
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Up-vector

        // Draw a rotating colorful triangle
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 14.0f, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(0.3f * (GLfloat) x + (GLfloat) t * 100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-5.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(5.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 6.0f);
        glEnd();

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers();

    }// Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while (glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) != GLFW_PRESS &&
            glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED));

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**Here is the output/errors:**

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cs335.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/triangle.o.d
gcc.exe    -c -g -I/C/MinGW/include/GL -I/C/MinGW/include -I/C/GLFW/glfw- 
2.7.8/include/GL -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/triangle.o.d -o     
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/triangle.o triangle.c

mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows 

gcc.exe -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cs335 build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/triangle.o -     
L/C/MinGW/lib -L/C/GLFW/glfw-2.7.8/lib -lmingw32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lglu32 -   
lopengl32 -lglfw -lglfwdll 

make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/triangle.o: In function `main':

C:/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335/triangle.c:17: undefined reference to   
`glfwInit'

C:/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335/triangle.c:23: undefined reference to 
`glfwOpenWindow'

C:/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335/triangle.c:26: undefined reference to 
`glfwTerminate'

C:/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335/triangle.c:30: undefined reference to 
`glfwSetWindowTitle'

C:/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335/triangle.c:33: undefined reference to 
`glfwEnable'

make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335'

C:/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335/triangle.c:36: undefined reference to 
`glfwSwapInterval'

C:/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335/triangle.c:39: undefined reference to 
`glfwGetTime'

C:/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335/triangle.c:40: undefined reference to 
`glfwGetMousePos'

C:/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335/triangle.c:43: undefined reference to 
`glfwGetWindowSize'

C:/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335/triangle.c:79: undefined reference to 
`glfwSwapBuffers'

C:/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335/triangle.c:81: undefined reference to 
`glfwGetKey'

C:/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335/triangle.c:81: undefined reference to 
`glfwGetWindowParam'

C:/Users/cseat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cs335/triangle.c:86: undefined reference to 
`glfwTerminate'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: * [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cs335.exe] Error 1
make[1]: * [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 866ms)
```

**And Here are screen shots of all the settings and links:**

[image: img]